# In a listview, how do I find the biggest number when it has a letter in front?

Tags: vb.net

I can't figure out how to find in a listview the "biggest value" when it has something like this in the list:

```
a001
a002
a124
**a455** << this is the "biggest"
a300
a200
```

They are files loaded from a folder.

In the listview there are also other items (files) called in another way: `v3432, d4234...` and so on.

I tried to order by name, but no chance to get something that really works.

My other code:

```
Dim query = (From F In IO.Directory.GetFiles(pdfFile)

Select Name = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(F), Full = F).ToList

For Each file In query Dim lstStuff As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem()

For colID = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count

  lstStuff.Text = CStr(colID)

Next

lstStuff.SubItems.Add(String.Join(", ", files))
'lstStuff.SubItems.Add(file.Name) lstStuff.SubItems.Add(".pdf") ListView1.Items.Add(lstStuff)
```

Comment: You want to get the highest number, regardless the letter ?

Comment: What is the data source for your listview? Just a string list? or something a bit more complex like a list of a custom type?  How is it constructed?

Comment: the letter is quite important

Comment: If the letter is important, why an order by name doesn't work ?

Comment: because I can't extract the value ,I don't want to do it manually , if I order then I have a list with ordered items, but how I know what is the biggest value?  i want that thing done it automatically and show it in a label or textbox

Comment: You've got 2 options the way I see it.  1) when construction your collection rather than just adding to the list, check the number at that point and insert the filename at the required location.  2) Use a custom class with the file name AND number component allowing you to order based on the number.  You chose what works best for you

Comment: One of the reasons that beginners in particular find it hard to solve problems is that they don't attempt to break a problem down into parts and identify the parts they can do and the parts they need to research. In this case, there are three major steps to the problem: getting the data from the `ListView`, extracting the number from the data and getting the largest number. All three of those steps can be tackled independently, so saying that you have a problem that involves all three is simply not accurate. It seems like your actual problem is extracting a number from alphanumeric text.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I'm understanding the issue that you're getting tripped up on, it's really just trying to compare the number value of each, so the simplest way I can think of would be to just "ignore" the first letter while comparing, and then "re-add" it again after the number compare, something like this:

```
Private Function Compare(strNumberA As String, strNumberB As String) As String
    
    Dim strStringA As String  = strNumberA
    Dim intResultA As Integer = Integer.Parse(strStringA.Substring(1))

    Dim strStringB As String = strNumberB
    Dim intResultB As Integer = Integer.Parse(strStringB.Substring(1))

    Dim strResult As String = String.Empty
    
    If intResultA > intResultB Then

        strResult = strNumberA & " is larger"
        
    Else
        
        strResult = strNumberB & " is larger"
        
    End If  
    
    Return strResult
    
End Function
```

or if you prefer ternary instead, like myself ;) :

```
Private Function Compare(strNumberA As String, strNumberB As String) As String
    
    Dim strStringA As String  = strNumberA
    Dim intResultA As Integer = Integer.Parse(strStringA.Substring(1))

    Dim strStringB As String = strNumberB
    Dim intResultB As Integer = Integer.Parse(strStringB.Substring(1))

    Dim strResult As String = If(intResultA > intResultB, strNumberA & " is larger", strNumberB & " is larger")

    Return strResult
    
End Function
```

Call it like:

```
Debug.Writeline(Compare("a3456", "v346"))
```

Returns:

> a3456 is larger

Obviously tweak this function as to suit your needs as necessary. How you choose to feed the string values to the function, and handle the result afterward I'll leave up to you.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to sort the results using a custom comparer and take the last value:

```
Dim query = (From F In IO.Directory.GetFiles(pdfFile)
             Select Name = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(F), Full = F).ToList

query.Sort(Function(a, b)
               Return CInt(a.Name.Substring(1)).CompareTo(CInt(b.Name.Substring(1)))
           End Function)

Dim largest = query.Last
Debug.Print("largest: name = " & largest.Name & ", Full = " & largest.Full)
```